# perl: pattern matching for comparision pair of string

Tags: regex, perl, string-comparison

I have a problem to count the majority selectedresult for each pair of string. my code: it seems just count if user choose either sysA, sysB or both without considering the pair of string. I'm also have a problem to make multiple comparision and deal with 7 users for each pair.

```
( $file = <INFILE> ) {
@field = parse_csv($file);
chomp(@field);
@query = $field[1];

for($i=0;$i<@query;++$i) {
    if ( ($field[2] eq $method) || ($field[3] eq $method)){
    if ( $field[4] eq $field[2]) {
    print "$query[$i]: $field[2], $field[3], $field[4]\n";
    $counta++;
    } 
    if ( $field[4] eq $field[3]) {
    print "$query[$i]: $field[2], $field[3]: $field[4]\n";
    $countb++;
    }
    if ( $field[4] eq ($field[2] && $field[3])) {
    #print "$query[$i]: $field[2]$field[3]\n";
    $countc++;

}
```

data: for each query, i have 3 different combination of string comparision.

- comparison("lucene-std-rel","lucene-noLen-rr");
- comparison("lucene-noLen-rr","lucene-std-rel");
- comparison("lucene-noLen-rr","random");
- comparison( "random", "lucene-noLen-rr");
- comparison("lucene-noLen-rr","lucene-nolen-rel");
- Comparison("lucene-nolen-rel","lucene-noLen-rr");

example data for one pair (7 users evaluate for each pair):

- user1,male,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-relrandom

  - user2,male,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-rel
  - user3,male,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-rel
  - user4,male,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-rel
  - user5,male,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-relrandom
  - user6,male,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-rel
  - user7,male,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-rel

example output required: query 1:male fitness models

- lucene-std-rel:5, random:0, both:2 ---> majority:lucene-std-rel

any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, without making this more complex than you requested, here is what I came up with as a possible approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my %counter = ( "A" => 0, "B" => 0, "AB" => 0, "majority" => 0);

while(<DATA>){

    chomp;
    next unless $_;
    my ($workerId,$query,$sys1,$sys2,$resultSelected) = split(',');

    $counter{$resultSelected}++;

}
$counter{'majority'} = (sort {$counter{$b} <=> $counter{$a}} keys %counter)[0];
print "A: $counter{'A'} B: $counter{'B'} both(AB): $counter{'AB'} majority: $counter{'majority'}\n";


__END__

user1,male,A,B,A

user2,male,A,B,AB

user3,male,A,B,B

user4,male,A,B,A

user5,male,A,B,A
```

The output of this is:
A: 3 B: 1 both(AB): 1 majority: A

I don't feel like my example to you fully addresses the idea of there being more than one type with the "majority". For instance, if both A and B are 9, I'd expect them both to be listed there. I didn't bother to do that since you didn't ask, but hopefully this will get you along the right path.

Comment: Well, you can open a CSV file pretty easily in Perl.

Just do open(FILE,"filepath.csv");, and change <DATA> to <FILE>

You'll need to do close(FILE); at the end of your script though.

Comment: thanks caterham. could you please make it if consider for 6 combination and help to do if both got same score as you mentioned

Comment: WorkerId,Input.query,Input.sysa,Input.sysb,Answer.selectedResultset
A2COB9JH3BL6IM,male fitness models,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-relrandom
A1M3165X1R2F8Z,male fitness models,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-rel
A2702L43B9JI9,male fitness models,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-rel
AZ92SE5L1P238,male fitness models,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-rel
A1DGNCZZWELLVX,male fitness models,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-relrandom
A2ZBU2WW9WHXB7,male fitness models,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-rel
A2ZH0XH25HXD1Y,male fitness models,lucene-std-rel,random,lucene-std-rel...

Comment: hi Caterham, i tried using the code & run through the program, yet unable to acquire the right output results via the existing input data file.

Comment: I think you need to provide more details to your post to get a better response. It isn't very clear (to me at least), what you are trying to do.

Comment: OK. got it. tq. hope you can still help me for another comparision.

Comment: I'd be happy to, just provide more details as to what you want. It looks clear from your code snippet that there is "more to it" than I took from your post.

Comment: i'm making the analysis of data for the evaluation comparing serach result for 41 query and rank using 4 different system. As evalution, i compare between two system. user will choose either sysA or sysB or both. 7 user work for each pair of system. comparison("lucene-std-rel","lucene-noLen-rr");
comparison("lucene-noLen-rr","lucene-std-rel");
comparison("lucene-noLen-rr","random");
comparison( "random", "lucene-noLen-rr");
comparison("lucene-noLen-rr","lucene-nolen-rel");
Comparison("lucene-nolen-rel","lucene-noLen-rr");

Comment: query 1: male fitness models with 3 pair (sysa,sysb)
lucene-noLen-rel 2 lucene-noLen-rr 4 both 1
lucene-std-rel 4 lucene-noLen-rr 1 both 2
lucene-noLen-rr 5 random 1 both 1

query 2: volkswagen passat picture
random 2 lucene-noLen-rr 4 both 1
lucene-noLen-rr 1 lucene-noLen-rel 3  both 3
lucene-noLen-rr 2 lucene-std-rel 3 both 2

Answer (score -1):

```
open( INFILE, "compare.csv" ) or die("Can not open input file: $!");

while ( $file = <INFILE> ) {
@field = parse_csv($file);
chomp(@field);
@query = $field[1];

for($i=0;$i<@query;++$i) {
    if ( ($field[2] eq $method) || ($field[3] eq $method)){
    if ( $field[4] eq $field[2]) {
    print "$query[$i]: $field[2], $field[3], $field[4]\n";
    $counta++;
    } 
    if ( $field[4] eq $field[3]) {
    print "$query[$i]: $field[2], $field[3]: $field[4]\n";
    $countb++;
    }
    if ( $field[4] eq ($field[2] && $field[3])) {
    #print "$query[$i]: $field[2]$field[3]\n";
    $countc++;

}

}
```

}

sub parse_csv {
    my $text = shift;
    my @new  = ();
    push( @new, $+ ) while $text =~ m{
       "([^\"\]*(?:\.[^\"\]*)*)",?
           |  ([^,]+),?
           | ,
       }gx;
    push( @new, undef ) if substr( $text, -1, 1 ) eq ',';
    return @new;
}`